# find table under table tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem i have to find span text which is under table but i can't i write this code:

```
var currentRow = $("#table").closest("tr.paging");
                //do something with values in td's
                var firstTDValue = currentRow.find("td").eq(0).children("span").text();
                 alert(firstTDValue);

<table>
<tr class="paging">
<td colspan="14">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span>1</span>
```

please can any one help me..

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: i have not the put full HTMl..

Comment: You need to put enough HTMl so that we can see that you don't have a problem with that.

Comment: @jai i think you should start the jquery first......

Comment: @jai yes i have to rude with you because you can'not annbody motivated you only depreciated...and that why you are heheheheheheeeeeeeee.

Comment: did you see a upvote for your comment _i have not the put full HMTL..._ that's me bro....yet you should get to this link `---->` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @jai okay you are right now you have to goooooooooooooooooooo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var a = $('.paging td span').text();
alert(a);
```

or

```
$('.paging td span').each(function(){
   var a = $(this).text();
   alert(a);
});
```

or in your code (remove # in table)

```
var currentRow = $("table").closest("tr.paging");
                //do something with values in td's
                var firstTDValue = currentRow.find("td").eq(0).children("span").text();
                 alert(firstTDValue);
```

Comment: Please stop using alert() for trouble-shooting. Use console.log() instead. http://spudley.com/blog/dont-use-alert-to-test-your-javascript-code

Comment: Thanks brother but sorry i can't give the marks...